# htaccess commenting doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

With the current htaccess, my site doesn't work and I get "Internal Server Error":

```
RewriteEngine on

# Disable Directory Browsing
# Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This is solved by deleting these lines from the syntax:

```
# Disable Directory Browsing
# Options All -Indexes
```

**As you notice, they are already commented, so deleting them should not make any difference, then why it does matter?**

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server logs regarding the 500 error?

Comment: Nope. where to look?

Comment: generally in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: It says:
[Tue Jan 05 09:06:42 2016] [alert] [client 5.28.177.182] /home/my_account/my_site/.htaccess: RewriteEngine must be On or Off, referer: http://officemore.co.il/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Tue Jan 05 09:06:42 2016] [alert] [client 5.28.177.182] /home/my_account/my_site/.htaccess: RewriteEngine must be On or Off

The value passed to `RewriteEngine` is not case-sensitive, so `on` (as in your code) and `On` should both work OK. It would seem the parser is reading something different to what we are seeing as the code you have posted should not result in this error.

It is possible that there are some strange/hidden characters or possibly corrupt line endings resulting in this error. Try retyping it, creating a new document (or exposing hidden characters in your editor)?

Comment: There really was some hidden charackters! I created a new htaccess and moved only visible text, not all the sytntax, and it worked!